# Limiting bluimp jquery upload to a single file

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have a scenario - where i only want a user to upload a single file (a profile image). I didnt see a way to allow this in the options.
Can someone comment on this?

Thanks in advance!

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: if you remnove the multiple attribute from input type it will allow  user to select single file only

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eLLWN/122/

Comment: great - if you add this as an answer, i will approve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remnove the multiple attribute from input type it will allow user to select single file only

```
<input type="file" name="file"/>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eLLWN/122/)